# WPF Initializing DP in Code vs. XAML

Tags: c#, wpf

When I declare a DP:

```
    public static readonly DependencyProperty StrokeThicknessProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("StrokeThickness", typeof(double),
        typeof(xxx), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(1.0));
```

Is there a difference between initializing it there vs. initializing it in the XAML style declaration? As in:

```
Property="StrokeThickness" Value="1.0"
```

As Peter indicated, the XAML method wouldn't be accessible in derived classes, but some properties are a pain to declare in the C# (i.e. brushes, geometry, etc).

Image a stop sign control. Should I put the background=red in the C# or declare it with a setter in the XAML? Same for the octagon geometry, etc.

Comment: If you have a _specific_ scenario in mind, you need to explain that. Without any particulars, your question is just a matter of opinion. But, assuming by "in the XAML" you mean that your object (e.g. a `UserControl` class) declares in XAML a value assigned to that same property, it's important to note that the two techniques are not semantically equivalent. When declaring a default value in the `DependencyProperty.Register()` call, that default is available to and overridable by subclasses, and can be modified by styles. If it's assigned as a local value in XAML, it can't be any of that.

Comment: @PeterDuniho, I have updated the question, but essentially yes, DP.Register() vs a XAML setter. In my stop sign example, if I don't set it in the C#, a derived stop sign wouldn't be red, it would be black. I don't see people declare stuff like brushes and geometries usually in the C#, just trying to figure out where to draw the line.

Comment: You should draw the line where it works for your needs. Anything beyond that is, again, a matter of opinion. I've already explained the semantic difference. Your code example doesn't really add much in the way of detail. If I were writing something that was literally a "stop sign control", I wouldn't provide any mechanism for the user code to modify the red color at all; that would be hidden as an implementation detail, inside the XAML elements that constitute the control. So that example doesn't help illuminate your scenario to me.

Comment: @PeterDuniho, ok... that makes sense, now lets say stop signs are blue in France, so you want to make the color configurable via a DP (assume something similar to a Background property). Would you let the C# side default to null or black and set the red in the XAML or would you set the red in the DP.Register? What about for something more complex, like a geometry? That's really what I'm getting at.

Comment: If you need different colors because of localization issues, you should have a property that sets the locale for the sign, and let the control determine how to display the sign (including background color) for that locale. Now, _that_ property would be a dependency property and IMHO the default should be set in the `Register()` call. But again, still opinion based.

Comment: @PeterDuniho Thanks. Digging around various controls with ILspy, it seems like Microsoft only sets basic bool, etc. values in the DP.Register(). Kind of seems like they stick to non look related props in the Register only. I'm still looking at controls, but I haven't found one where they set colors and stuff in the code side.

Comment: Note that both can exist at the same time. A dependency property can have multiple "value sources", and there is [value precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/dependency-property-value-precedence). A value from a Style Setter has higher precedence than a default value.

Answer (score 0):

The `FrameworkPropertyMetadata` that you pass to the `DependencyProperty.Register` defines the actual default value of the dependency property across all instances. It is part of the definition of the type.

A style setter in a style is only part of a `Style`, even if it happens to be the default style for the control.

So if you as a control author really rely on a dependency property to have a default value, you should specify this value when you register the dependency property. This should be part of the definition of the property/type.

Comment: My consternation about it is what default values are appropriate to put in the Register() and which go in the default style. It seems that MS doesn't put things like colors/brushes in the Register(), but your control is uninitialized. I'm building a star rating control. Its fine to Register() the default star count of 5, but if I don't specify yellow for the color, they'll be null / not drawn. Seems weird to specify a default of black in the C# and then my custom yellow in the XAML... also seems weird to specify my custom yellow in the C# and then the star geometry in the XAML, etc.

Comment: There is no right or wrong basically. It is up to you as a control author to decide :) There are plenty of things that you can do one way or another without any of them being wrong.